# python pass object as argument

Tags: python, oop, object

How can I pass an object as an argument to a class method and call the method of the passed object when the class method is called?

Say I have:

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def myfunc(self, something):
        something.do()


anobject = blah.xyz()

another_obj = myclass()
another_obj.myfunc(anobject)
```

Comment: In case you didn't know, a class does not need to have an `__init__` method.  `def __init__(self): pass` is redundant.

Comment: @mgilson I think you should say Not required instead of Doesn't need.

Answer (score 14):

So long as `something` has a `.do` method, that should work as given (once you fix your indentation and order of declaration). Have you tried running it?

This is (more or less) how a lot of standard functions work - for example, the built-in `len` function is pretty much

```
def len(obj):
    return obj.__len__()
```

Answer (score 0):

Which method of the past object do you want to call?

By the way, `myfunc` is an instance method.

Comment: "passed" object, not "past."

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this

```py
class FirstClass:
    def method1(self):
        print("method1 from Firstclass")

    def call_outside_method(self):
        return outside_method(self)


def outside_method(fc: FirstClass):
    return fc.method1()


a = FirstClass()

a.call_outside_method()
>> method1 from Firstclass
```

- See the `outside_method` is taking a `FirstClass` type object as an input parameter and from the `FirstClass` class we defined the `call_outside_method` method which is passing the current object to the `outside_method` function.
  Here we have passed `FirstClass` object to the `outside_method` function. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score -6):

```
class student :
 ID=0
 name=""

def fun(s=student()):
  print (s.id)
  print (s.name)


st=student()
fun(st)
```